# Macro for Calculating the No of months(count) between Two months

Tags: vba

I want to write a macro to calculate the no of Months(Count) between two months (strings)

Means, I want to know how many months are there between January to August
The result should show as 8.. I know how to write using Dates(Numbers), But using Month strings i have no idea..It would be of great help if anyone guide me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't too clear, but if I understand you correctly then you can use the following formula:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1" & A1 &"2014"))-MONTH(DATEVALUE("1" & B1 &"2014"))
```

Where A1 and B1 each contain a month name as a string. So for example if A1 was August and B1 was January, then the formula would show '7' as the output.

Using VBA, you can use the same code, replacing A1, B1 and C1 with the relevant ranges:

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1" & A1 &"2014"))-MONTH(DATEVALUE("1" & B1 &"2014"))"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Answer, This is the method i used to calculate..But here the actual requirement is A1 should be " January" and B1 should be August not in Date-time format..A1 & B1 should be as Month names..Now how do we calculate the no of months between these two months ?

Comment: I've amended my answer to transfer the month string to a number representing the Excel date-time code, and then calculate the difference. Let me know if this works.

Comment: With pleasure. Can you please accept the answer and vote it up - it would be good to get my reputation up! ;)